# Did Obi-Wan ever lie to Luke?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, return-of-the-jedi, the-empire-strikes-back, armada

In Ernest Cline's book 'Armada', the protagonist calls Obi-Wan a 'bold faced liar', referencing Obi-Wan's time on Tatooine watching over Luke as he grew up, and the training that Obi-Wan provided Luke with. I know that Obi-Wan's story of what happened to Luke's father wasn't exactly the truth, but it wasn't exactly a lie either. Is there any time in the original trilogy when Obi-Wan bold-faced lied to Luke?

Comment: Obi-Wan also told Luke that he and Darth Vader had the same teacher. That's not true, since Obi-Wan was the one who taught Anakin (and was himself taught by Qui-Gon).

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen where did he do that? In A New Hope, he says "A young Jedi called Darth Vader, who was a pupil of mine before he turned to evil..."

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Their primary training came from different sources, but that's not to say they didn't share some teachers (e.g. if Yoda occasionally taught them both, even if he wasn't their primary trainer, then they still could be said to have had the same teacher). And that's even without getting into vagaries such as whether "The Jedi Academy" counts as their teacher in this context. It could all be true, from a certain point of view.

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen - *technically*, Anakin's first teacher *was* Qui-Gon.  So that is true --- from a certain point of view.

Comment: Okay, I misremembered the thing about Obi.Wan and Anakin having the same father. However, Obi-Wan did tell Luke some obvious untruths, given what happened in Ep. 3:
"I haven't gone by the name Obi-Wan since oh, before you were born."
" I have something here for you. Your father wanted you to have this [light sabre] when you were old enough."